# Trying to make a random command for my Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have separate folders for each command. I have them connected to the main.js - this is my GIF folder.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'gif',
    description: "this is a gif!",
    execute(message, args){
        
        if (message.content === "-gif") { // checks if the message says "?random"
                const number = Math.random(); // generates a random number
                message.channel.send(number.toString()); // sends a message to the channel with the number
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it generates random numbers. I'd like it to generate random GIFs (but I want to add all of the random GIFs it chooses from with links).

Comment: I would make an array of the gif links (I’m not sure where you are getting them from so I don’t know if you can automate the array construction) and use number to reference and index in that array. Use [int](math.random() * myArray.length) to get a relevant index once you have the array.

Comment: I am getting them from tenor.com

Comment: I am new to making a discord bot. Can you show me an example code?

Answer (score 0):

**Defining Discord**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = Discord.Client();
```

**Adding a message event listener**

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    //code goes here
});
```

**Generating a random link from an array**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // defining the discord.js module
const client = Discord.Client(); //defining the bots client

client.on('message', message => { //a message event listener
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('-gif') { // checking if the message is equal to "-gif"
        var gifs = ['linkToGif', 'linkToAnotherGif', 'etc'] //creating your array
        var response = Math.floor(Math.random * gifs.length); //getting a random number from the array
        message.channel.send(gifs[response] //sending the random link from the array
    }
});
client.login('yourToken');
```